# Context must not be null

Tags: android, json

Verán, tengo una clase la cual me funciona correctamente, pero, las imágenes que no se ven en la pantalla se quedan pasando como si estuviera buscando la correcta, entonces he agregado la librería de `Picasso`:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getEscudo_local())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)
    .into(holder.escudo_local);
```

La aplicación se cierra, y este es el `logcat`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null
```

Y este el código completo:

```
public class Estadisticas_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Estadisticas> {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<Estadisticas> Estadisticas_List;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public Estadisticas_Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Estadisticas> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        Estadisticas_List = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.escudo_local = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_esc_local);
            holder.escudo_visi = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_esc_visi);

            holder.tv_Nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Equipo_Local);
            holder.tv_Nombre_Local = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Equipo_Local);
            holder.tv_Nombre_Visi = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Equipo_Visi);
            //holder.tvNombre_Arbitro = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Nombre_Arbitro);
            holder.tv_Fecha = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Fecha);
            holder.tv_Hora = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Hora);
            holder.tv_Result_Local = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Result_Local);
            holder.tv_Result_Visitante = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Result_Visitante);
            /*holder.tv_Targeta = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_targeta);
            holder.tv_Tar_Minuto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_tar_minuto);
            holder.tv_Gol_Minuto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_gol_minuto);
            holder.tv_Nombre_Entra = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre_entra);
            holder.tv_Dorsal_Entra = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_dorsal_entra);
            holder.tv_Nombre_Sale = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre_sale);
            holder.tv_Dorsal_Sale = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_dorsal_sale);
            holder.tv_Cambio_Min = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_cambio_min);*/
            holder.tv_Estado_Partido = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Estado_Partido);
            //holder.tv_Num_Goles = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Num_Goles);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getEscudo_local())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)
                .into(holder.escudo_local);

        //holder.escudo_local.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        holder.escudo_visi.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        //new DownloadImageTask(holder.escudo_local).execute(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getEscudo_local());
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.escudo_visi).execute(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getEscudo_visitante());

        //holder.tvNombre_Arbitro.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getNombre_Arbitro());
        holder.tv_Nombre.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.tv_Nombre_Local.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getNombre_Local());
        holder.tv_Nombre_Visi.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getNombre_Visi());
        holder.tv_Fecha.setText("Fecha: "+Estadisticas_List.get(position).getFecha());
        holder.tv_Hora.setText("Hora: "+Estadisticas_List.get(position).getHora());
        holder.tv_Result_Local.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getResult_Local());
        holder.tv_Result_Visitante.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getResult_Visitante());
        //holder.tv_Targeta.setText("targeta: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getTargeta());
        //holder.tv_Tar_Minuto.setText("Targetamin: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getTarMinuto());
        //holder.tv_Gol_Minuto.setText("golmin: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getGol_Min());
        //holder.tv_Nombre_Entra.setText("Nombreentra: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getNombre_Entra());
        //holder.tv_Dorsal_Entra.setText("dorsalentra: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getDorsal_Entra());
        //holder.tv_Nombre_Sale.setText("Nombreentrasale: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getNombre_Sale());
        //holder.tv_Dorsal_Sale.setText("dorsalsale: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getDorsal_Sale());
        //holder.tv_Cambio_Min.setText("cambiomin: " + Estadisticas_List.get(position).getCambio_Min());
        holder.tv_Estado_Partido.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getEstado_Partido());
        //holder.tv_Num_Goles.setText(Estadisticas_List.get(position).getNum_Goles());
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv_Nombre;
        public TextView tv_Nombre_Local;
        public TextView tv_Result_Local;
        public TextView tv_Result_Visitante;
        public TextView tvNombre_Arbitro;
        public TextView tv_Fecha;
        public TextView tv_Hora;
        public TextView tv_Nombre_Visi;
        public TextView tv_Targeta;
        public TextView tv_Tar_Minuto;
        public TextView tv_Gol_Minuto;
        public TextView tv_Nombre_Entra;
        public TextView tv_Dorsal_Entra;
        public TextView tv_Nombre_Sale;
        public TextView tv_Dorsal_Sale;
        public TextView tv_Cambio_Min;
        public TextView tv_Estado_Partido;
        public TextView tv_Num_Goles;

        public ImageView escudo_local;
        public ImageView escudo_visi;

    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;


        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;

        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        }

    }
}
```

¿Me pueden dar alguna solución?

Gracias Angel Angel, la solución:

```
public Estadisticas_Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Estadisticas> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        Estadisticas_List = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Comment: Tal vez agregar `this.context = context;` en el constructor?

Comment: Gracias si esa es la solución.

Comment: Una pequeña recomendación, glide es más eficiente en mostrar imágenes, su sintaxis es muy parecida a picasso

Comment: Por favor, *no añadas la respuesta a tu pregunta en el texto de la pregunta*. Para eso están las respuestas.  Si tu solución particular es una variación de una respuesta ya dada, *añade tu propia respuesta* o bien acepta dicha respuesta.

Comment: Perdón estaba con el movil y no he podido hacerlo así.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta parte quizas sea la que le este lanzando el error:

```
//..
Context context;
//..
public Estadisticas_Adapter(Context context, int resource,  ArrayList<Estadisticas> objects) {

    super(context, resource, objects);
```

Usted oculta el `context` que inicializa en super, podría tratar de usar `this.context = context` debajo del constructor, si esto le funciona, podría refactorizar el código si es necesario para no llamar a context en la clase base o quizas pueda hacerla protect y no usar `Contex context` en la clase `Extadisticas_Adapter` pues lo hereda (que tampoco se como esta en la clase base solo lo dejo como observacion), o eliminar el `Contex contex` de la clase y usar el de la clase base pero no se si esto es posible porque no se de que manera esta en la clase base ni lo que hara usted con contex en la clase `Extadisticas_Adapter`, pero básicamente creo que es porque `Contex contex` no esta inicializado en esta clase pero si en la clase base, pero aunque en la clase base sea visible para la clase derivada, este esta quedando oculto, y el que es visible `Contex contex` no esta inicializado.

Comment: Gracias Angel Angel, la solución: